# GWT PRESENTER MOCKING

Tags: gwt, mocking, mockito

Is it a good practice for using `GWT.create` for instantiating a Asynchronous Interface in the GWT Presenter?

The reason why i am asking is i need to write Junit test cases for the presenter (i dont want to use the GWTTESTCASE) and using mockito to mock and stub things that i require.

But i cannot mock on these Asynchronous interfaces because i am using GWT.create to create them

Please let me know in case more details are required

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An instance of the asynchronous interface should be passed to the presenter via a constructor or set method, so all the GWT.create calls are outside the Presenter. This allows you to pass in a mock instance within the Junit tests.